# iPhone:Notification when picture/video taken

Tags: iphone

I know how to access photo album using UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary on iPhone development. But i want my application to get notified whenever there is any photo or video taken using built-in camera by user. How can i achieve this functionality on iPhone development? Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to be notified of these events.

If you were to start the camera/video recording from within your app then you would know when the user had finished taking the picture.

Comment: Ok. Yes, i know that launching camera to take picture and coming back to my app.